# Python: Logging TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, logging, string-formatting, python-logging

Here is a quick reproduction of the issue:

```
>>> import logging
>>> logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
>>> from datetime import date
>>> date = date.today()
>>> logging.info('date={}', date)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 846, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 723, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 464, in format
    record.message = record.getMessage()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 328, in getMessage
    msg = msg % self.args
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
Logged from file <stdin>, line 1
>>>
```

How do I make it work?

---

<sub>This is effectively a special case of [Why do I get "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting" trying to substitute a placeholder like {0} using %?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18053500) - but because the actual formatting step happens outside the user's code, different workarounds are necessary.</sub>

Comment: In my case, I was trying to pass an exception object to exception level: `logger.exception('msg', exception_obj)`, similar to how I used to pass with error level. Remove the object and let it handle the exception logging for you.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You could do the formatting yourself:

```
logging.info('date={}'.format(date))
```

As was pointed out by Martijn Pieters, this will always run the string formatting, while using the logging module would cause the formatting to only be performed if the message is actually logged.

Comment: Do know that by doing the formatting yourself, you loose the speed advantage offered by letting the logging module do it for you *only when the message is actually logged*. In other words, if you use the `debug()` handler but the logging level excludes DEBUG level, you are not incurring the penalty of the string formatting operation. The speed difference can be significant if you have a lot of debug messages.

Comment: I expect heavy calculations even on [logging.debug("my huge structure: %s", json.dumps(my_huge_structure, indent=2))]  when debug level is INFO. Its easy to make logging calls wrapper and replace arguments with parameterless lambdas with their calculated values on logging: [wrapper.debug(("my huge structure: %s", lambda: json.dumps(my_huge_structure, indent=2))]

Answer (score 76):

You cannot use new-style formatting when using the logging module; use `%s` instead of `{}`.

```
logging.info('date=%s', date)
```

The logging module uses the old-style `%` operator to format the log string. See the [`debug` method](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.debug) for more detail.

If you really want to use `str.format()` string formatting, consider using custom objects that apply the formatting 'late', when actually converted to a string:

```
class BraceMessage(object):
    def __init__(self, fmt, *args, **kwargs):
        self.fmt = fmt
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def __str__(self):
        return self.fmt.format(*self.args, **self.kwargs)

__ = BraceMessage

logging.info(__('date={}', date))
```

This is an approach the [Python 3 `logging` module documentation proposes](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-custom-message-objects), and it happens to work on Python 2 too.

Answer (score 7):

Martijn's answer is correct, but if you prefer to use new style formatting with logging, it can be accomplished by subclassing Logger.

```
import logging

class LogRecord(logging.LogRecord):
    def getMessage(self):
        msg = self.msg
        if self.args:
            if isinstance(self.args, dict):
                msg = msg.format(**self.args)
            else:
                msg = msg.format(*self.args)
        return msg

class Logger(logging.Logger):
    def makeRecord(self, name, level, fn, lno, msg, args, exc_info, func=None, extra=None):
        rv = LogRecord(name, level, fn, lno, msg, args, exc_info, func)
        if extra is not None:
            for key in extra:
                rv.__dict__[key] = extra[key]
        return rv
```

Then just set the logging class:

```
logging.setLoggerClass(Logger)
```

Comment: Or even (at least on Python 3.5) use just LogRecord with `logging.setLogRecordFactory(LogRecord)`

Answer (score 6):

You could do also (Python 3);

```
logging.info(f'date={date}')
```

Comment: It's only for Python 3.6 onwards though. It also evaluates eagerly, while logging module evaluates messages lazily

Comment: ... but all parameters are evaluated even before passing to logging call. Look at my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

If you are more familiar with print statements, print directly into logger

```
logging.info(print("Test:" , variable))
```