# Why do I get "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting" trying to substitute a placeholder like {0} using %?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, typeerror, output-formatting

I have some code which will read two strings from the user:

```
name1 = input("Enter name 1: ")
name2 = input("Enter name 2: ")
```

Later, I want to format those strings into a longer string for printing:

```
if len(name1) > len(name2):
    print ("'{0}' is longer than '{1}'"% name1, name2)
```

But I get an error message that looks like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program.py", line 13, in <module>
    print ("'{0}' is longer than '{1}'"% name1, name2)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

What is wrong with the code? How should I write this line instead, in order to format the string properly?

---

<sub>See also [String formatting: % vs. .format vs. f-string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/) for in-depth comparison of the most common ways to do this kind of string formatting, and [How do I put a variable’s value inside a string (interpolate it into the string)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960772) for a general how-to guide for this kind of string construction. See [Printing tuple with string formatting in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455602) for another common cause of the error.</sub>

Answer (score 292):

Old-style `%` formatting uses `%` codes for formatting:

```
# A single value can be written as is:
'It will cost $%d dollars.' % 95

# Multiple values must be provided as a tuple:
"'%s' is longer than '%s'" % (name1, name2)
```

New-style `{}` formatting uses `{}` codes and the `.format` method. Make sure not to mix and match - if the "template" string contains `{}` placeholders, then call `.format`, don't use `%`.

```
# The values to format are now arguments for a method call,
# so the syntax is the same either way:
'It will cost ${0} dollars.'.format(95)

"'{0}' is longer than '{1}'".format(name1, name2)
```

Comment: in python 3.6: `f"'It will cost ${your_variable} dollars."`

Comment: suppliment to @JinSnow comment.. if you want the variable name also to be printed, `f"'It will cost {your_variable=} dollars."`

Answer (score 64):

The correct way to use traditional string formatting using the '%' operator is to use a printf-style format string (Python documentation for this here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

```
"'%s' is longer than '%s'" % (name1, name2)
```

However, the '%' operator [will probably be deprecated in the future](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html). The new [PEP 3101](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/) way of doing things is like this:

```
"'{0}' is longer than '{1}'".format(name1, name2)
```

Comment: scnr: "will probably be deprecated in the future" did not happen so far (Python 3.5). The old '%' syntax wasn't deprecated in [3.1](https://docs.python.org/3.1/whatsnew/3.1.html) and only in 3.2 [logging module learned how to format with the new style `{}`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/whatsnew/3.2.html#logging). And suddenly 3.5 brings [PEP 461: `%` formatting for bytes](https://docs.python.org/3.5/whatsnew/3.5.html#pep-461-formatting-support-for-bytes-and-bytearray). This makes me think the `%` remains for a long time to come.

Comment: `%` is more concise. Glad it stays with us.

Comment: I concur. % is more concise and removing would add no benefit to the language.

Comment: @LenarHoyt How do you feel about f-strings?  I can't imagine that is `"'%s' is longer than '%s'" % (name1, name2)` more concise than `f"'{name1}' is longer than '{name2}'"`

Comment: I'm all for f-strings, but they're too new and you can't use them on project that is more than a year old

Comment: f-strings are often more concise, but there are some instances where `%` is still superior, e.g. when you want to do multi-line computations for the arguments or computations containing other strings.

Comment: f-strings kinda suck because they allow arbitrary code execution in ways that can be counterintuitive

Answer (score 57):

This error is also caused when [trying to format a single value into the string using `%`, if the value is a tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455602).

As shown and explained in Alex Martelli's answer there:

```
>>> thetuple = (1, 2, 3)
>>> print("this is a tuple: %s" % (thetuple,))
this is a tuple: (1, 2, 3)
```

> Making a singleton tuple with the tuple of interest as the only item,
> i.e. the `(thetuple,)` part, is the key bit here.

Comment: I would rather convert the tuple to a string using one of the following statements: `print("this is a tuple: %s" % str(thetuple))` or `print("this is a tuple: %s" % repr(thetuple))`

Answer (score 7):

Keep in mind this error could also be caused by forgetting to reference the variable

```
"this is a comment" % comment #ERROR
```

instead of

```
"this is a comment: %s" % comment
```

Answer (score 4):

In python 3.7 and above there is a new and easy way. It is called f-strings. Here is the syntax:

```
name = "Eric"
age = 74
f"Hello, {name}. You are {age}."
```

**Output:**

```
Hello, Eric. You are 74.
```

Comment: This doesn;'t actually answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

For me, as I was storing many values within a single print call, the solution was to create a separate variable to store the data as a tuple and then call the print function.

```
x = (f"{id}", f"{name}", f"{age}")
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Most Easy way typecast string number to integer

```
number=89
number=int(89)
```

Comment: This refers to an unrelated problem. Please see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15496408.

Answer (score -1):

I encounter the error as well,

```
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

But list args work well.

I use mysqlclient python lib.  The lib looks like not to accept tuple args. To pass list args like `['arg1', 'arg2']`   will work.