# inserting data into mysql using python with external variables

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I have a table where I need to populate email addresses from `txt` file, date  and source from `python` variables. Down the code, `a` is the variable am getting from `txt` and `b`, `c` are the python variables I need to insert along

```
import csv,MySQLdb,os,os.path,datetime as dt
from sys import argv
path = argv
prompt = '>'
filename = raw_input(prompt)
fname = os.path.basename(filename)
source = fname
print "",source
date = dt.datetime.today().strftime("%d/%m/%y")
date_log = date
print "",date_log
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","passwd","testdb")
x = db.cursor()
csv_data  = csv.reader(file(filename))
for row in csv_data:
    print row
    query = (" INSERT INTO test(a,b,c) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)",row)
    x.execute(query, (date_log, source))
db.commit()
db.close()
```

Here am getting some error as follows:

```
File "csv2mysql.py", line 31, in <module>
    x.execute(query, (date_log, source))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py",line159,in execute
    query = query % db.literal(args)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'tuple' and 'tuple'
```

any help is much appreciated

Comment: query is not fine... checkout the query string...                                       Your query is like something ('INSERT INTO test(a,b,c) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)', (val1, val2,...))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace query string

```
 query = (" INSERT INTO test(a,b,c) VALUES %s") %(row,)
```

or

```
 query = (" INSERT INTO test(a,b,c) VALUES %s") % str(row)
```

Hope it will work for you...

Comment: Hi Dhaval , i changed the query as u said, am getting this error, can u suugest what to do                ['a_121withme@indiatimes.com']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "2csv2mysql.py", line 27, in <module>
    x.execute(query, (date,fname))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 159, in execute
    query = query % db.literal(args)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: It will be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18053500/typeerror-not-all-arguments-converted-during-string-formatting-python