# Error while uploading file with Management API

Tags: google-analytics-api

I'm uploading csv with costs to Management API and today get an error from API "not all arguments converted during string formatting".
How can I understand what i'm doing wrong?

File size is 656762

Comment: Please provide the full stack-trace and or JSON error response. As this is a [common python error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18053500/typeerror-not-all-arguments-converted-during-string-formatting-python) can I assume you are using the Python client libraries?

Comment: Shame on me. It's my mistake. I'm so sorry.
Thanks for you patience.