# Python: TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python

We re-installed one of our servers and a newer version of python was installed.  Since that happened, we get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):ogress: 0%
  File "/var/www/scripts/apollo_file_management_v3_FC.py", line 368, in <module>
    main()
  File "/var/www/scripts/apollo_file_management_v3_FC.py", line 362, in main
    delivered()
  File "/var/www/scripts/apollo_file_management_v3_FC.py", line 223, in delivered
    if cursor_2.execute("SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE `wt` = ?",(d[0])):
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 187, in execute
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

The guy that wrote the script doesn't work here anymore and the rest of us have never programmed in python.

Please let me know if you require additional info in order to assist.

Comment: Check it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18053500/typeerror-not-all-arguments-converted-during-string-formatting-python

Comment: @MarcCabos: that doesn't help when it is a library that has this issue.

Comment: Specifically, `(d[0])` does not create a tuple; `(..)` just groups an expression. Tuples are created by using a *comma*, and the `(...)` parentheses just group that comma with the right expression to disambiguate it from the commas used in a function call. `(d[0],)` would work, as does `[d[0]]` (to create a list).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PEP 249: Python Database API Specification v2.0](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/)

The second argument to `execute()` must be a sequence.

```
(d[0],)
```