# logging.debug error during string formatting

Tags: python

I am trying to print a variable using `logging.debug` and running into below error,how to fix it?

```
logging.debug('ATTEMPTS:{0}',attempts)
```

Error:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 846, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 723, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 464, in format
    record.message = record.getMessage()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 328, in getMessage
    msg = msg % self.args
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18053500/typeerror-not-all-arguments-converted-during-string-formatting-python)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you should try as

```
logging.debug('ATTEMPTS:{0}'.format(attempts))
```

Answer (score 3):

You could either use

```
logging.debug('ATTEMPTS:%s', attempts)
```

or

```
logging.debug('ATTEMPTS:{0}'.format(attempts))
```

The first method passes two parameters into the logging.debug function which will automatically format the log. The second method passes in a single pre-formatted string into the logging.debug function.

Answer (score 0):

You're [formatting the string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) incorrectly, try:

`logging.debug('ATTEMPTS:{0}'.format(attempts))`