# getting "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting" this error when am inserting data from csv to mysql

Tags: mysql, python-2.7

I am inserting 4 columns `js_id[varchar]`, `name[varchar]`, `email[varchar]`, and `js_signup[varchar]` into mysql by reading a `csv` file.

I keep getting this error

> "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting".

My code is below.

```
 import csv
 import MySQLdb
 mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',user='root',passwd='Yogi123$',db='wisdom_india')
 cursor = mydb.cursor()
 csv_data = csv.reader(file('test_csv.csv'))
 for row in csv_data:
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO testcsv(js_id, \
      js_name,js_email,js_signup )' \
      'VALUES(%s, %s, %s, STR_TO_DATE(%s,'%%m/%%d/%%Y %%h:%%i'))', 
      row)
 mydb.commit()
 cursor.close()
 print "Done"
```

Comment: someone please help me where am going wrong

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18053500/1531971

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18053500/typeerror-not-all-arguments-converted-during-string-formatting-python)

Comment: Formatted error as a quote. Fixed grammar.