# Not all arguments converted during string formatting operation

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm doing exercise 14 from the Zed Shaw's "Learn python the hard way" but having this problem. I have even tried copy pasting the code from the book but it always gives me that error. Here's my code:

```
from sys import argv

script, user_name = argv
prompt = ' >'

print ("Hi %s I'm the %s script.") % (user_name, script)
print "I'd like to ask you some questions"

print ("Do you like me?") % (user_name)
likes = raw_input(prompt)

print ("Where do you live %s") % (user_name)
lives = raw_input(prompt)

print ("What computer do you use %s") % user_name
uses = raw_input(prompt)

print """ 

Alright so I asked you if you liked me and you said %r. You live in %r and you use 
%r computer. Thanks
""" % (likes, lives, uses)
```

What's causing this error?

Comment: Try running each set of set of statements individually, one by one, til you figure out what line is causing the error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18053500/typeerror-not-all-arguments-converted-during-string-formatting-python)

Comment: FYI, Shaw's book is somewhat out of date (and therefore wrong in some places) now since he refused to migrate to Python 3. You might want to look for something else.

Comment: @jpmc26 Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: My only suggestion is read through the answers in the question I suggested is a duplicate. There are a couple different possible causes, but they're all detailed there in answers. And also switch to Python 3 as soon as possible. No sense confusing yourself with old stuff that's aging away now.

Comment: @jpmc26 What I meant by suggestion was, which book do you suggest would be best

Answer (score 0):

This line looks wrong:

```
print ("Do you like me?") % (user_name)
```

Comment: For not explaining anything, -1. (This is also a duplicate.)

Answer (score 0):

Change the statement

```
print("Do you like me? %s") % (user_name)
```

You gave the variable as an argument but you didn't have a placeholder for the argument. That's why it cannot convert the argument to string during formatting.

Comment: Im sorry, I dont understand. If I write that, it gives me error that "username" is undefined

Comment: user_name is your variable. The arguments you use after % are your variables. Mine had a typo earlier.

Comment: Im sorry i still don't understand.What should I do correct the error?

Comment: This is incomplete. There's also the issue with the fact the OP is passing in a string instead of a tuple or list. (This is also a duplicate.)

Answer (score 0):

For what I understand the problem is with this line

```
print("Do you like me? %s") % (user_name)
```

and also with the fact that you don't pass an argument to the script, which is supposed to be bound to the **user_name** variable (this is why you get undefined).

Call the script like this:

```
$ python filename.py Muhammad
```