# Python not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following python code

```
table += '<tr><td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td></tr>'% format(str(key)), 
format(str(value))
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting" trying to substitute a placeholder like {0} using %?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18053500/why-do-i-get-typeerror-not-all-arguments-converted-during-string-formatting-t)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing three different methods of converting values to strings. To use the `{..}` placeholders, use the [`str.format()` *method*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format), directly on the string literal that is the template:

```
table += '<tr><td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td></tr>'.format(key, value)
```

There's no need to use the [`str()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#str) or [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format) functions, and you don't need to use `%` either.

- The `format()` function turns objects into a string using the [*format specification mini language*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec), the same language that lets you format the values in a `str.format()` placeholder. It's the formatting part of the template language, available as a stand-alone function.
- `str()` turns an object into a string *without* specific formatting. You'll always get the same result. Because `str.format()` already converts objects to strings (but *with* formatting controls) you don't need to use this. And if you need it anyway (because, say, you want to apply *string* formatting controls and not those of another object type), `str.format()` has the `!s` conversion option.
- Applying `%` to a string object gives you a different string formatting operation called [*`printf`-style formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting). This method is much less flexible than the `str.format()` version.

If your are using Python 3.6 or newer I recommend you use the faster [f-string formatting string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings):

```
table += f'<tr><td>{key}</td><td>{value}</td></tr>'
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the `.format` method on the string. Just like this:

```
table += '<tr><td>{key}</td><td>{value}</td></tr>'.format(key=str(key), value=str(value))
```