# Error: Not all argument converted during string format in zmq

Tags: python, string, format, zeromq

I am trying to give host and port info separately but i get the error as mentioned in the question. The reason is because the zmq takes only the link like address for example 'tcp://192.X.X.X:5643'. So i am unable to give the host address by myself or either just type it. I want to provide host address seperately because i get my host address from other function so its easier to pass to a variable.

Here is the code:

```
def req_con:
    Context=zmq.Context()
    socket=context.socket(zmq.REQ)
    aad="192.x.x.x"
    port =8574
    host=["%s".format(aad,port)]
    for adres in host:
       socket.connect("tcp://" %adres) ---> error is here
       socket.send_string("get")
```

Updated:

```
def req_con:
..
..
host:['{p.aad}:{p.port}'.forma(p=req_con())]
```

I tried to make it better but now i get maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a python object error

Comment: You are mixing up two styles of string formatting.  I recommend reading up on string formatting.  This site seems to give a nice overview : https://pyformat.info/
The host you're trying to connect is '%s'.

I think you want something like this :
host = "%s:%s" % (aad, port)

Comment: The same error persists @Q-life

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18053500/typeerror-not-all-arguments-converted-during-string-formatting-python)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by

```
host="192.x.x.X"
port=...
socket.connect("tcp://" "%s:%d" %(format(host),port))
```

Comment: I'm glad it works but your syntax is weird and, honestly, I think there's no reason for the format function. Why do you think you need it ? If you replace the socket.connect() call by print() you can easily see that syntax I suggested first really should work.
`>>> print("tcp://" "%s:%d" % (format(host), port))`
output : `tcp://192.x.x.X:8574`

`>>> print("tcp://" "%s:%d" % (host, port))`
output : `tcp://192.x.x.X:8574`

`>>> print("tcp://%s:%d" % (host, port))`
output : `tcp://192.x.x.X:8574`

Comment: If i do not use format then i get an error saying all strings are not converted so i had to use it.

Answer (score 0):

`.format()` is an easy way in strings:

```
host = "192.x.x.x"
port = 1234
socket.connect("tcp://{}:{}".format(host, port))
```