# update column a values to column b corresponding to particular id in python

Tags: mysql, python-2.7

I have written a code to read 2 columns(raw_id, notes) from mysql db using pymysql, which gives me list of dictionary. Now I want to extract id values, store it and update review column  with notes column values for every raw_id at the record level. Can anybody help me with this.

db_data contains:

```
[OrderedDict([(u'raw_id', u'52c00'), (u'notes', u'awesome')]), 
OrderedDict([(u'raw_id', u'54df0'), (u'notes', u'loved it')]),
OrderedDict([(u'raw_id', u'5cd00'), (u'notes', u'enjoyed')]),...]
```

Code I've used:

```
for row in db_data:
    text = row.values()
    r_id = text[0]
    update_sql = "update raw_data set review = notes where 
    customer_id = {0} and raw_id = {1}"
    res = sql_db.execute_write(update_sql, [inp_cust_id, r_id])
    print res
```

Error I'm getting:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18053500/typeerror-not-all-arguments-converted-during-string-formatting-python

Answer (score 0):

```
for row in db_data:
    text = str(row.values())
    r_id = str(text[0])
    update_sql = "update raw_data set review = notes where 
    customer_id = {0} and raw_id = {1}"
    res = sql_db.execute_write(update_sql, [inp_cust_id, r_id])
    print res
```

***try this***