# TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting 2.0

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

I am attempting to call back to a split list I made and am getting this error:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Here is my code:

```
user_string = (input('Enter input string: \n'))

if ',' not in user_string:
    print ('Error: No comma in string.\nEnter input string: ')

if ',' not in user_string:
    print ('Error: No comma in string.\nEnter input string: ')

if ',' not in user_string:
    print ('Error: No comma in string.\nEnter input string: ')    

else:
    print (user_string)

new_tokens = user_string.split (',')

print('First word: ' %s (new_tokens[0]))

print('Second word: ' %s (new_tokens[1]))
```

Comment: Is the repetition in the code intentional? Did you misplace the `%s`? If not your code should give an error along the line of `NameError: name 's' is not defined` if this is the full code.

Comment: the repetition is intentonal

Comment: where should the %s go?

Comment: Like [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5082452/11941443).

Comment: Take a look at [Python's many ways of string formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13451989/2745495).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18053500/typeerror-not-all-arguments-converted-during-string-formatting-python)

Comment: how would I get the loop to check for the input

Comment: You should strip down your code to a [mcve]. In particular, you should remove the manual input, unless that is the cause of the problem. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong with the code.

**First**, the string formatting:

```py
print('First word: ' %s (new_tokens[0]))
print('Second word: ' %s (new_tokens[1]))
```

Python has [many ways to format strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13451989/2745495). You seem to be trying to use the [`printf`-style formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting) from C, but you've misplaced the `%s` character. It should be `format % values`:

```py
print('First word: %s' % (new_tokens[0]))
print('Second word: %s' % (new_tokens[1]))
```

Note that, while there is no problem with `%`-style, if you are already on Python3, it's better to use the `.format()` syntax or the newer the f-strings syntax introduced in Python3.6.

**Second**, the input prompts:

```py
user_string = (input('Enter input string: \n'))

if ',' not in user_string:
    print ('Error: No comma in string.\nEnter input string: ')
```

My understanding is, you're prompting the user for a string but it needs to have a comma. If the input does not have a comma, you prompt the user again. But the problem with your code is that **you don't update `user_string`**. It does not magically or automatically get updated, you need to re-assign the `input` value again to `user_string`.

If you have a predefined number of attempts the user can make (it looks to be 3 based on your example), you can make a loop that prompts until max attempts are made or until the user provides correct input. It would look something like this:

```py
user_string = ""

max_attempts = 3
current_attempt = 0
while (current_attempt < max_attempts):
    # Get user input
    # Python2
    user_string = raw_input('Enter input string: \n')
    # Python3
    #user_string = input('Enter input string: \n')
    # Check if user input is correct
    if ',' not in user_string:
        print('Error: No comma in string.')
        current_attempt += 1
    else:
        # Stop the loop
        break

print(user_string)
if current_attempt == max_attempts:
    print('Error: I told you to input string with comma')
else:
    # rest of the code
```

Comment: Enter input string: 
Enter input string: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 7, in <module>
    user_string = (input('Enter input string: \n'))
EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3? You need to use `raw_input` for Python2. I thought you were using Python 3 based on the `print` statements. But anyway I edited the code for the 2 ways of getting input based on Python version.