# TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting in psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, pycharm, psycopg2

When I run the below code with psycopg2:

```
cur.execute(
    """INSERT INTO logmsg (msg_type, file, msg) VALUES %s;""",
    ["Error", str(file), str(sys.exc_info()[0])])
```

I get the following error:

> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Which version of Python is this? You could be causing issues with mixing format functions between Python2.x and Python3. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18053500/typeerror-not-all-arguments-converted-during-string-formatting-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VALUES` needs a list of values enclosed in brackets:

```
cur.execute(
    """INSERT INTO logmsg (msg_type, file, msg) VALUES (%s, %s, %s);""",
    ["Error", str(file), str(sys.exc_info()[0])])
```

Do not forget to commit the transaction.