# Pythons string formatting

Tags: python, string, printing

I get the error "SyntaxError: invalid syntax", though I am not really sure why:

```
print("ChiSquare Elektronen, Myonen, Tauonen und Hadronen %d",%( chisquare(fitElectrons, wertElectrons, errorE[0]), chisquare(fitMyons, wertMyons, errorE[0]), chisquare(fitTauons, wertTauons, errorE[0]), chisquare(fitHadrons, wertHadrons, errorE[0]) )
```

Comment: Drop the comma before "%" in `,%`. The percent sign is used as an operator (like `+`, `-`, `*`, etc.).

Comment: Delete the ',' after format string, its "format string" % (agr1, arg2, arg3...), without the ','

Answer (score 2):

The comma is not required before the `%` or modulus.
Correct syntax : `print("ChiSquare Elektronen, Myonen, Tauonen und Hadronen %d" %( 1 ))`

Additionally, you do not have a valid int type on the right-hand side of the % operator.
They seems be, for example : `1,3,5,2` 
This cannot be converted to float as this contains the `,`.

Rather use it this way:
`print("ChiSquare Elektronen, Myonen, Tauonen und Hadronen %d %d %d %d" %(1,3,5,2))`

or

`print("ChiSquare zum Elektronen ist %d, zum Myonen ist %d, zum Tauonen ist %d und zum Hadronen ist %d" %(1,3,5,2))`

Comment: Thanks! So if I understand you correctly, the `%`-operator should not be used for floats, right?

Comment: You can. For printing float type use `%f` instead of `%d`.
FYI, %f simply prints the whole float value. And Ex: %6.2f prints the float such that the length of the number is 6 and the decimal part is just 2.
Ex: for the number 13.45 applying %6.2f gives us 13.4500
for the number 123.456768 applying %6.2f gives us 123.45

Comment: Thanks again, I find it really interesting. When I use `print("\nP-Werte Eektronen, Myonen, Tauonen und Hadronen: {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}".format(pvalElectrons, pvalMyons, pvalTauons, pvalHadrons))`, I obtain "P-Werte Eektronen, Myonen, Tauonen und Hadronen: 0.8396741761875282, 0.9994747318207605, 0.9753723367002908, 0.9700954166525304", when I use `print("\nP-Werte Eektronen, Myonen, Tauonen und Hadronen: %f %f %f %f" %(pvalElectrons, pvalMyons, pvalTauons, pvalHadrons))`, I instead obtain 0.839674 0.999475 0.975372 0.970095. How could I get more digits as in the first case?

Comment: The `%f` prints 6 decimals as a default value. And hence the values are rounded off.
But the `{0} or {1}` are simply place holders. So what ever are provided in the `format()` are just replaced. This could be any type, a string as well.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the suggested comments do NOT work for me. However, the following line works (cf. [TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18053500/typeerror-not-all-arguments-converted-during-string-formatting-python) for more details):

```
print("ChiSquare Elektronen, Myonen, Tauonen und Hadronen '{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}'" .format( chisquare(fitElectrons, wertElectrons, errorE[0]), chisquare(fitMyons, wertMyons, errorE[0]), chisquare(fitTauons, wertTauons, errorE[0]), chisquare(fitHadrons, wertHadrons, errorE[0])))
```