# Passing parameters to LIKE SQL query

Tags: python, sql, fastapi

I want to pass dynamic parameter to the LIKE query using Fast API (Python) coming from the query parameter. I have tried a lot of ways but I don't know what I am doing wrong.

The query I need to use is :
`SELECT Time, table_id, Text FROM tablename WHERE Text LIKE '%text%'`

The python code for getting query parameter is :

```
def get_result(text : str):
   con = connection.connect()
   statement = 'SELECT Time, table_id, Text FROM tablename WHERE Text LIKE '%text%''
```

How will I pass the dynamic text parameter in this query because this gives the error saying **"TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting"**?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18053500/typeerror-not-all-arguments-converted-during-string-formatting-python)

Comment: ***NEVER*** substitute values directly in to a SQL string like that.  ***EVER***.  Use parameterised queries / bind variables.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot nest single quotes. Also, it's clearer to use a f-string for string formatting here. Try:

```
statement = f"SELECT Time, table_id, Text FROM tablename WHERE Text LIKE '%{text}%'"
```

Comment: ***NEVER*** substitute values directly in to a SQL string like that.  ***EVER***.  Use parameterised queries / bind variables.

Comment: Its not working...If I try to print this it's simply printing the same line without putting the text value inside.

Comment: @MatBailie kinda true, but it depends on whether text comes from unsanitized input or not. If you know that arbitrary SQL cannot be injected into `text`, then it does not matter. Also, your point is irrelevant to the questioners problem.

Comment: @Xandra you are probably missing the `f` character in front of the string.

Comment: It does matter.  It hides bugs, relies on implicit data-types, breaks query plan caching,  is harder to maintain, etc, etc.  ***NEVER*** do this.

Answer (score -1):

***NEVER*** substitute values directly in to a SQL string like that.  ***EVER***.  Use parameterised queries / bind variables.

For example, depending on the driver/library you're using, you may be able to use...

```
con = connection.connect()
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT Time, table_id, Text FROM tablename WHERE Text LIKE %s", ('%' + text + '%',))
```