# A TypeError prevents me from forming the conditionals of my function (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

The function is supposed to receive a number representing a year, and then print if it's a leap year or not.

```py
def isItALeapYear(year):

    while True: 
        if year % 4 == 0:
            print("That is a leap year! ")
            break
    
        elif year % 4 != 0:
            print("That is not a leap year...")
            break

        elif not isinstance(year, int) or year == None:
            print("Please enter a number...")
            break
```

The program works, the only thing I can't get right is that it is supposed to notify you if anything that it's **not** a number is being used as an argument. I've tried both the *isinstance()* function, as well as writing what I want as *year != int*. And then *year == None* in the hopes of making it work in case anything nondefined is used as an argument.

I read this post with the exact same error: [TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18053500/typeerror-not-all-arguments-converted-during-string-formatting-python)

But I'm not intending to format anything with the % symbol
As far as I'm concerned the % can be used as an operand to get the residue of a division.
So in this case I'm using it to figure out if a year is a leap year or not by asking if the residue is 0 when divided by 4. I'm pretty stuck, and the sad thing is the error comes up in the very first "if", so I can't really know if the last lines for excluding any non int type argument work or not. Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the exact error traceback? It seems likely though that this is because your type check is at the end. The code will still attempt to perform modulo operation first, which won't work if it is not an `int`.

Comment: Check its type before you try and do arithmetic on it.

Comment: The `isinstance` conditional should be the first of the 3, not the last

Comment: Hi @Shize and welcome to SO! You should check the value for it's type outside of the function and only pass it if it's numeric. Also the while loop makes no sense at all.

Comment: Can I just point out that the calculation to determine a leap year is *inaccurate*. A leap year which is mod 4, and mod 100, is *not* a leap year, unless it is mod 400.  [Here is a simple explanation](https://www.mathsisfun.com/leap-years.html).  And the `while` loop is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to divide the functionality of checking the number from returning the output as well as from receiving the input.

```py
def is_multiple_of_four(number: int):
    if number % 4 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    user_input = ""
    while not user_input.isdigit():
        user_input = input("Please type in a year: ")

    if is_multiple_of_four(int(user_input)):
        print("That is a leap year!")
    else:
        print("That is not a leap year.")
```

Here you can see the function that checks the number does only that, it checks the number if it's modulo of 4 equals 0.
In the script outside the function you can retrieve the user input for as long as it takes to get a valid numeric and return the output in respect of the functions results.

**Edit** (adding clarification asked in the comments)

The first condition `if __name__ == '__main__'` is quiet common in python. It's not necessary for your function, but I like using it in answers if people seem to learn Python, so they don't miss out on it. Here is a question with a good answer: [What does if __name__ == "__main__": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do/419185#419185)
The ***short answer*** in the accepted answer is enough to understand why you might want to use it.

The second condition

```py
    user_input = ""
    while not user_input.isdigit():
```

first defines a variable *user_input* with an arbitrary **non-digit String** value and than uses the negated *isdigit()* method of the *String* class on it as condition. Therefor the while loop gets entered in the beginning, as the arbitrary value is not an digit. From then on the value will be re-assigned with user input until it holds an actual digit. This digit is still a *String* however.

Comment: This works wonderfully, I should have considered using an actual input. It also feels like a super clean and pretty solution. I managed to finish creating the function with no issues following this. There is just one thing that I would like to understand, because it kind of feels bad using someone else's code and not understanding it. What exactly is that "empty" if condition.

if __name__ == '__main__':
    user_input = " "

I don't really understand what it's doing. But if I take it out, or replace the words it doesn't work. So it seems pretty important.

Comment: @Shize - It’s *not* required for your specific use case; with some minor refactoring.  This construct (which I’d recommend researching to fully understand) is essentially used to run a script as a program; whereas it appears you are simply searching for a function to call.   It’s overkill in this situation.  That aside, it’s an inefficient and *inaccurate* calculation and should not be used without modification to correct the inaccuracy. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71992043/6340496) is the correct solution.

Comment: I see! I must have removed it before defining it as an actual function. Now it works just fine without it. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Shize I edited my answer to address your questions. As you might have noticed I changed the name of the function, from the beginning. It's name represents what it actually does. Also you might want to check out the answer considering the _calender_ library. I assume you want to train python coding and this is totally fine. For production code I strongly recommend not implementing anything regarding character encoding, or dates/time and rather use existing libraries.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [`isleap()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.isleap) function from the standard library (module [`calendar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html)):

```
from calendar import isleap

def isItALeapYear(year):
    if not isinstance(year, int):
        print("Please provide a number")
    elif isleap(year):
        print("That is a leap year!")
    else:
        print("That is not a leap year...")
```

Comment: This is the actual fixed version of the code in the question. +1

Answer (score 2):

First thing `while loop` in the function makes no sense you can remove it(If you want).

There are multiple ways to do that I will show.

First One.

```py
def isItALeapYear(year):
    if type(year) != int:
        return         # here return to exit the function 
    while True: 
        if year % 4 == 0:
            print("That is a leap year! ")
            break
    
        elif year % 4 != 0:
            print("That is not a leap year...")
            break

        elif not isinstance(year, int) or year == None:
            print("Please enter a number...")
            break
```

Another is.

```py
def isItALeapYear(year):
    try:
        int(year)
    except ValueError: # this line of code executes when the year is not the int
        return  # here return to exit the function 
    while True: 
        if year % 4 == 0:
            print("That is a leap year! ")
            break
    
        elif year % 4 != 0:
            print("That is not a leap year...")
            break

        elif not isinstance(year, int) or year == None:
            print("Please enter a number...")
            break
```

I know there are more ways to do that but these are the best ones (I Think).

Your function is not accurate then you can use this one.

```py
def isItALeapYear(year):
    if type(year) != int:
        return
    if (( year%400 == 0)or (( year%4 == 0 ) and ( year%100 != 0))):
        print(f"{year} is a Leap Year")
    else:
        print(f"{year} is Not the Leap Year")
```

#### Edit For Quetioner

```py
def isItALeapYear(year):
    if type(year) != int:
        return
    if (( year%400 == 0)or (( year%4 == 0 ) and ( year%100 != 0))):
        print(f"{year} is a Leap Year")
    else:
        print(f"{year} is Not the Leap Year")
try:
    isItALeapYear(asdasd)
except NameError:
    print("You give the wrong Value")
```

Comment: The leap year calculation is inaccurate. And this is an unnecessary abuse of a `try/except` block.

Comment: @S3DEV This is not what the OP wants.

Comment: @S3DEV Now OP's function is accurate.

Comment: I tried the first one and it works. The only thing is, what if the user using the function chooses to input some random combination of letters as an argument. It works if I a pass it a string, like this isItALeapYear("akwhfuh") and I made it do a print and quit. But what if the user does isItALeapYear(ksduj)? I get "Name error: ksduj is not defined". That would be the very last thing I need to solve. A way for the program to notify the user they cannot input anything random.

Comment: @Shize Now you can check

Comment: Please don’t suggest that users to accept your answer.  I’d bleeds of desperation and is poor form.

Comment: @S3DEV Okk, Bro.